# LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cannot be converted to EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I don't understand, what is happening at all!

Suddenly, simple things stopped to work!

Now ehen I am trying to define something like here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.java-config

I get the following compile error

```
incompatible types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cannot be converted to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
```

And this is correct, since [`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) does not implement [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html), which is required by [`JpaTransactionManager#setEntityManagerFactory()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html#setEntityManagerFactory-javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory-) method.

How it cn be, that official example contains absolutely incorrect snippet? How it can be, that this snippet was compiling for me for some time?

What I broke?

**UPDATE**

I was able to rewrite

```
txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
```

to

```
txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
```

So it is an error in the doc?

Comment: Have you tried to check the versions of jars you're using? You said that this has started to happen "suddenly"... Maybe its an attempt to upgrade something? In any case please specify the versions of spring, hibernate and so forth

Comment: Version is `1.10.6.RELEASE` to which doc is belong to. Hibernate is not involved in the problem. I remembered what I changed: I removed `getObject()` because there is no `getObject()` in example. I tried to be closer to the doc, but sunk in Spring hell.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the documentation is wrong

Use this code to inject entity manager factory into txManager

```
@Bean @Autowired public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);
    return txManager;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
```

is not suppose to work you either have to do this

```
txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
```

or

```
txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory()
```

so honestly I don't know why it previously worked.

I guess it is a mistake since I tried that way as described in the official doc and It didn't work